# Expanding and Collapsing a bootstrap accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have unknown number of accordion controls like this on my page that I generate the id for them at run time by looping through my results:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordionMessagesSetup">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionMessagesSetup" href="#collapseMessagesSetup">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
                    Message Setup
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseMessagesSetup" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div>
                <p style="background-color: red"> Someting ELSE in here</p>
                <p style="background-color: red"> Someting ELSE2 in here</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Live Demo of code above: http://www.bootply.com/jDrg0bMiiV

How can I collapse or expand them all by pressing a button ? ( for example a Collapse All button on the page and an Expand All button on the page.)

Comment: Try this example http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/4O4DW  or http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/3kB4m ...Both are working fine..which uses bootstrap

Comment: @VinothNarayan thankam my own code does collapse and expand if I manually click on it, I just don't know how to do it programatically so user can click a button and do it

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In your example, you just have to code two buttons using bootstrap [collapse methods](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-methods):

- [`.collapse('show')`](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapseshow)
- [`.collapse('hide')`](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapsehide)

---

```
// SHOW BUTTON:
$("#collapse_show").click(function(e) {
    $(".panel-collapse").collapse("show");
});

// HIDE BUTTON:
$("#collapse_hide").click(function(e) {
   $(".panel-collapse").collapse("hide");
});
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://www.bootply.com/ARQsNqs35i)

Comment: This solution - which I upvoted - has a small problem - or not - depending what you want to accomplish. When accordion has more than one panel and you want to open another panel, panel opened by code above will not close. In such case, it is better to use: $(".panel-collapse").addClass("in");

Answer (score 8):

You may use [collapse('toggle')](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/collapse/#collapseoptions):

```js
$(function () {
  $('#toggleAccordions').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.panel-collapse').collapse('toggle');
  })
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button id="toggleAccordions">Collapse / Expand All</button>
<div class="panel-group" id="accordionMessagesSetup">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionMessagesSetup" href="#collapseMessagesSetup">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
                    Message Setup
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseMessagesSetup" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div>
                <p style="background-color: red"> Someting ELSE in here</p>
                <p style="background-color: red"> Someting ELSE2 in here</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel-group" id="accordionMessagesSetup1">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionMessagesSetup" href="#collapseMessagesSetup">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
                    Message Setup
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseMessagesSetup1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div>
                <p style="background-color: red"> Someting ELSE in here</p>
                <p style="background-color: red"> Someting ELSE2 in here</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel-group" id="accordionMessagesSetup2">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionMessagesSetup" href="#collapseMessagesSetup">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
                    Message Setup
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseMessagesSetup2" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div>
                <p style="background-color: red"> Someting ELSE in here</p>
                <p style="background-color: red"> Someting ELSE2 in here</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just make a part of the id static (id="collapsible") and then use a jQuery wildcard.

In your button you can do something like this $("id^=collapsable]").collapse('toggle');

This will match any id beggining with collapsible and toggle it.

Comment: instead of "id" can  jsut use "class="panel-group"  as I don't use it for anything else on the page.   If yes, can you please provide a more functional example I can follow ? I don't know much jQuery really.

Comment: Yes, class match seems better. Also you want to collapse/hide all not toggle but it's similar. Please check this solution http://www.bootply.com/peFUdnwOpZ

Answer (score 2):

I did just that on my current project. Here's how to do it in javascript :

```
    $("#your_button").click(function(event) 
    {
        // if you use an hyperlink like I do
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).blur();

        var hideAll = true;
        $(".panel-details").each(function() 
        {
            if (!$(this).hasClass("in")) {
                hideAll = false;
            }
        });
        $(".panel-details").collapse(hideAll ? "hide" : "show");
    });
```

The panel looks like this :

```
<div class='panel'>
    <a data-parent='#accordion' data-toggle='collapse' href='#'>
        <div class='panel-heading'>
            <h4 class='panel-title'>
                Panel title
            </h4>
        </div>
    </a>
    <div class="panel-details panel-collapse collapse <?=$firstPanel?'in':''?>">
        <div class='panel-body'>Panel content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, "panel-details"  in your code will be "panel-group" in my case?

Comment: @Bohn oh sorry, forgot to mention that. I'll update the answer.